# Angular controller doesn't pass value to web api method with $http

Tags: angularjs, http, post

This is my angularjs code:

```
var uname = resetPasswordRequestData.email
var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: workModule.config.Config.CommonUrl + "api/ResetPasswordRequest",
    data: uname
});
```

web api code:

```
public class PerformPasswordResetController : ApiController
{
    public int PerformResetPassword([FromBody]string uname)
    {
        CrmUser contact = null;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                contact = new PasswordResetProvider().GetUserByName(uname);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
}
```

My problem is when I make the call from Fiddler it works, but when I run the code it nicely rout to the web api method but in web api controller "uname" argument is null. when I pass some data from fiddler it pass that data to "uname" (in web api controller uname is not null)

[image]

can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with your server, but try changing the content type around. Also, inspect the call in the Network tab in Google chrome vs what Fiddler passes. Maybe there's some difference you overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you use a Model class to receive the data on your server.

Something like this:

```
public class UserModel {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class PerformPasswordResetController : ApiController
{
    public int PerformResetPassword([FromBody]UserModel user)
    {
        ...Do your stuff
    }
}
```

And on your angular code:

```
var model = {
    userName: resetPasswordRequestData.email
};

var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: workModule.config.Config.CommonUrl + "api/ResetPasswordRequest",
    data: model
});
```

Also, if you don´t want (or can´t) change your server code, try this please:

```
var uname = resetPasswordRequestData.email
var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: workModule.config.Config.CommonUrl + "api/ResetPasswordRequest",
    data: {
        uname: uname
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried with both way still doesn't pass the value to controller method... :(